# PHP Sockets - Store User login

Tags: php, sockets, session, websocket, client

Hey there I'm trying to implement a PHP Socket service which is used for a simple shoutbox.
This shoutbox has a simple login form and a authentication system which is based of sessions.

When the user logins a post requests gets made comparing the values with the database and if they are valid then create a session under that user.

Since these sessions would be stored on the clients computer I was wondering how the PHP Socket would be able to obtain these when it's running on the server. So the PHP Socket would be running on the server and try to obtain the session from the server but the session is stored on the users PC on login.

I already have the shoutbox running in PHP and HTML5 Sockets the only issue is the login step which I'm not entirely sure how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Info:

- Cookies are stored in browser, but sessions are always stored on the server.

In this case you could store the session ID in a database and pass it along to the socket call, which can verify it from the database.

Issues with login on web (http) and using session within socket

- passing session ID from http to socket could be also reused on another computer and then fake a successful login.
- login on http expires after a certain time, which does not mean that socket connection has ended
- ending socket connection does not log out from http

Secure approach

- pass username and password on first call within socket to login securely. Since socket remains open the user is authenticated and you dont need to pass any session.
- once socket closes session will also close

Comment: So I'm guessing that you mean, send over the username and pass over the socket, send back with a status e.g. "logged in" and store this on the server aswell.

Comment: Yes correct :) but you dont need to "store" this inside DB or so as it stays in the running session.

Comment: would it be secure to send over the password over the regular socket connection? I send the username and message in a json format so should I just add another variable for password or does the password have to be send over in a more secure way?

Comment: You can use SSL to improve security of socket connection (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php#98616)

This will prevent that data is being transferred in plain text (as you should do also on http calls).

Please dont try to do your own encryption or security implementation. Its much better to rely on stable and proven libraries (like ssl) You can use some JS based encryption libraries if you like, but only with random connection tokens, no hardcoded values

Comment: no worries I have used SSL before in fact the site itself is running over SSL right now so all requests are made securely.
Thanks for your help though it's much appreciated

Comment: Great, just be aware ssl over socket is a bit more complex to setup than plain https :)